# is there a way to send a command on chrome: YouTube

Tags: windows, cmd, youtube

I am trying to automate a process.

The idea is to open a youtube website on a specific link then play the video in fullscreen.

I managed to maximise the website by send the command via chrome.exe properties by adding `-kiosk` on the target section.

Chromes home page is set to the youtube link. however, I need to be able to have the stream open on fullscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used "Auto Hotkey" to mimic the users action and run the script when the pc turns on, and also opening chrome and running the same script via a batch file.